# Page become a client component when server action is defined?

Tags: next.js

I have a server action defined like the following,

```
const Home = () => {
  const create = async (formData: FormData) => {
    "use server";
  };
  return (
    <main>
      <form action={create}>
        <input name="name" />
        <button type="submit">Add</button>
      </form>
    </main>
  );
};
```

By default, Next.js will make `Home` a Server Component.

Then, I purposely removed `user server` from the server action and Next.js will complaint with this error,

```
 - error Error: Functions cannot be passed directly to Client Components unless you explicitly expose it by marking it with "use server".
```

Note Next.js now treat `Home` as a Client Component, but why?

Comment: How do you conclude that it is a client component now? Because it isn't, that much is clear.

Comment: When you're using action, you must make it a client component as it involves user interaction, after which you have to make that function a server action for performing anything on server

Comment: FabioNettis, because the error said functions cannot be passed directly to Client Components ....

adityanithariya, in the Next.js documentation, server action can be defined inside the component that uses it (Server Components only). I believe this is what I am doing now.

I think the error should really be,

Functions cannot be passed directly to Server Components unless you explicitly expose it by marking it with "use server".

Comment: I have the same doubt and I have been searching for this question and solution of it for the whole day and finally found the question. But sad that no answers are present

Answer (score 1):

when you pass the `action` prop to the form component next.js considering it to be a client component. it is not because of server action. if you have this code:

```
  <form action={() => null}>
```

this will throw the same error.

> Note Next.js now treat Home as a Client Component, but why?

Next.js is not treating Home as a client component. In server `Home` component, you are rendering client `form` element. Server Components prohibit direct passing of regular functions to client components, preventing potential vulnerabilities or unintended behavior. the only exception is passing server actions. But when you removed `use server`, the create function wasn't recognized as a server action.

Answer (score 0):

`form action={create}` makes your component a client component. You can call server actions from a Client component, but it needs to be defined in another file. create a new file "actions/create.ts" and import the function in your component.

From the docs:

> Client Components can only import actions that use the module-level
> "use server" directive.
>
> To call a Server Action in a Client Component, create a new file and
> add the "use server" directive at the top of it. All functions within
> the file will be marked as Server Actions that can be reused in both
> Client and Server Components:

Other option : You can also create your form as a child client component and pass the server action as a prop :

```
<ClientForm action={create}/>
```